# WifiManager.startScan() not calling onReceive() on a phone

Tags: android

I need to connect to a device via wi-fi and I am using `WifiManager.startScan()` for this. In theory `onReceive()` should be called back, but this doesn't happen. The code just keeps waiting for the callback.

The thing is that this code actually works fine on a Samsung tablet with Android 8.1, but it doesn't on any phones that I have tried (*Huawei Android 8.0 and Samsung Android 9*).

Here is the relevant code:

```
public void Init()
{
    try {
        mainWifiObj = (WifiManager) act.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiScanReceiver wifiReceiver = new WifiScanReceiver(act, logger, mainWifiObj);
        act.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(wifiReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        mainWifiObj.startScan();            
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ...
    }
}


public class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

...

public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {

    try {            
        ...// doesn't get here
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ...
    }
    ...

}
```

And here are the all important manifest permissions I used:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

The code doesn't generate any errors, it just silently fails to perform the callback.

Comment: Hi, did you find any fix?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I found the answer. For a reason logical only to Android designers, you must enable Location Based Services for it to work. So it's not enough to give all the needed permissions to your app, but also go to settings and enable LBS.

The reason why it worked on the tablet is that LBS were enabled on it...but how is one supposed to keep all these dependencies under control?

Comment: How does one enable LBS? Via the device? API call?

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to check is that you're not registering the broadcast receiver using

> LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);

use:

> mContext.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);

Comment: What is mContex?